# How can I change my variable to the players preference?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just started to try and get back into coding in python by writing this simple "game" but I can't get nrange and unumber to equal the players preference.

Here is the code I've written so far,

```
import random
import time

nrange = 10
rnumber = random.randint(1, nrange)
unumber = 1

def start():
    nrange = input("How many numbers do you want to guess between? ")
    unumber = input("What will your number guess be? ")
    main()

def main():
    print ("Number Reveal in...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    nreveal()

def nreveal():
    if rnumber == unumber:
        print("The Number was ", rnumber, " Well done you guessed correctly",)
        tryagain = input("Do you wanna play again? (Y/N)")
        if tryagain == ("Y"):
            start()
        if tryagain == ("N"):
            print ("Ok, hope you enjoyed playing")
            time.sleep(2)
            quit()
    if rnumber != unumber:
        print("The Number was ", rnumber, " sorry but you guessed wrong",)
        tryagain = input("Do you wanna try again? (Y/N)")
        if tryagain == ("Y"):
            start()
        if tryagain == ("N"):
            print ("Ok, hope you enjoyed playing")
            time.sleep(2)
            quit()

start()
```

Comment: Put `global nrange, unumber` at the top of `start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign to `nrange` and `unumber` in `start()`, they are local variables to that function, and changes you make to them are not seen elsewhere. To modify the global variables, simply declare them global in`start()`:

```
def start():
     global nrange, unumber
     # rest of code as you have it
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with your code:

- You only generate the random number once
- You aren't updating the `global` variables in `start`
- You need to convert inputted numbers to `ints`.

---

The first point should be fairly self explanatory (`rnumber` is only set in the main body of code and never modified), and the second issue can be seen through the following snippet:

```
>>> a = 5
>>> def b():
...     a = 6
... 
>>> b()
>>> a
5
>>> def c():
...     global a
...     a = 6
... 
>>> c()
>>> a
6
```

---

So, with the `...` section the same as in your question, the following should now work:

```
import random
import time

rnumber, unumber = 0, 0

def start():
    global rnumber, unumber
    nrange = int(input("How many numbers do you want to guess between? "))
    unumber = int(input("What will your number guess be? "))
    rnumber = random.randint(1, nrange)
    main()

 ...
```

---

And it does! Here is my test run:

```
How many numbers do you want to guess between? 100
What will your number guess be? 4
Number Reveal in...
3
2
1
The Number was  37  sorry but you guessed wrong
Do you wanna try again? (Y/N)Y
How many numbers do you want to guess between? 1
What will your number guess be? 1
Number Reveal in...
3
2
1
The Number was  1  Well done you guessed correctly
Do you wanna play again? (Y/N)N
Ok, hope you enjoyed playing
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed

Comment: @Callum Please accept (grey --> green arrow next to answer) then! Thank you :)